# how to get variable in jade/pug's custom filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I want to write a filter in jade/pug
this is my filter:

```
pug.filters.testfilter = function (text) {
  console.log(text);
};
```

I ues it in `.pug file`:

```
li 
  :testfilter
    #{tag.date}
```

the tag data is `{'date': ISODate("2017-03-10T08:17:29.672Z")}` 
I want to get `ISODate("2017-03-10T08:17:29.672Z")` in `testfilter`
But when I console.log it, it give me `#{tag.date}`

how can I get the real value in filters?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, `#{tag.date}` is only evaluated and rendered to text when compiled. Prior to that, it is just text in the file. What you're asking for runs counter to the order of operations. Pug will first perform the filter, then render the template.

Comment: how can I realize it?